# allow html2canvas to display images and download with images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html2canvas

i have been trying to get an answer for this question for the past 3 days and cant seem to find an answer for my question. my code is very long please forgive me. the reason why my code is long is because i have to take all the variables in consideration i asked the same question and left out some code and when i tried integrating it into my page it did not work.what i want is for my dog image to show in my shirt image when i download it but right now i get a blank download. here is a live code http://torcdesign.com/evol/

```js
function fctCheck(gender) {
  var elems = document.getElementsByName("subselector");
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems.item(i).style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(gender).style.display = "block";
}
$('#men').on('change', function() {
  $("#mtsm").css('display', (this.value == 'tsm') ? 'block' : 'none');
});



$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.colore.active').each(function() {
    $('.container ').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data("image") + ')');
  });
  $('.colore').on('click', function() {
    $('.container').css('src', '');
    $('.container ').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data("image") + ')');
    $('.container7').css('background-image', 'url(' + $(this).data("image-back") + ')');
  });
  $('#toggler').click(function() {
    var tmp = $('.container').css('background-image');
    $('.container').css('background-image', $('.container7').css('background-image'));

    $('.container7').css('background-image', tmp);
  });
});localStorage.option1 = "wow cool option text here"
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#imajes').change(function() {
    $('.subselector').hide();
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
 
  });
  
    $('.smallimages').hide();
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    var val = $(this).val();
 
 
$('#dog').on('change', function() {
  
  $("#bulldogimges").css('display', (this.value == 'bulldog') ? 'block' : 'none');



});

$('img').on('click', function() {
    $('#fotos').append('<div class="imgdrag"><img class="modal-content" src="' + $(this).attr('src')+ '"/></div>'); $('.imgdrag').draggable();
$('#fotos').droppable();
            $('.modal-content').resizable();


$(".download").attr("href",$(this).attr('src'));
  $(".download").show();
});

  
  
});





var download = document.getElementById("download"),
  result = document.getElementById("previewImage");

function renderContent() {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById("firstshirt"), {
        allowTaint: true
    }).then(function(canvas) {
      result.appendChild(canvas);
        download.style.display = "inline"; download.href = result.children[0].toDataURL();
    });
}

function downloadImage() {
  
}

document.getElementById("btn-Preview-Image").onclick = renderContent;
download.onclick = downloadImage
```

```css
.container {background-color: transparent;
    width: 490px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 2px solid;
    position: relative;
overflow: hidden;

/* Will stretch to specified width/height */
  background-size: 490px 500px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;

}.colore {
  float: left;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
.white {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}.black {
  background: #000000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://hongru.github.io/proj/canvas2image/canvas2image.js"></script>

<script  
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Philosopher' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/master/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script src="https://files.codepedia.info/uploads/iScripts/html2canvas.js"></script>


<div id="firstshirt" class="container" style="float:left;">
<center><div id="wrapper"><div id="boxes" class="container5" style="float:center;">
 <div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
   <div class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">
        
      
      
</div></div>

<a href="" download><span id="image" class="preview-area"></span></a><div id="fotos" ><img class="modal-content" id="imgdisplay" /></div></div></div></center><br><br><br><br></div>
<input id="btn-Preview-Image" type="button" value="Preview"/><a id="download" download="my_image.png" href="#">Download image</a>

<select id="Gender" onchange="fctCheck(this.value);">
        <option value="">Choose Gender</option>
        <option value="men">Men</option>
   
    </select>  
   
    <select id="men" name="subselector" style="display:none">
      <option value="">Choose an item</option> 
      <option value="tsm">T-Shirt</option>
    
    
    </select>  
  
     
            
           <div style='display:none;' id="mtsm">
    <div class="colore white" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/shirts/white.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="colore black active" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/shirts/black.jpg">
    </div>
   </div><p></p>
<select id="imajes">
        <option value="">Choose Image</option>
        <option value="new-upload">Upload Image</option>
        <option value="dog">Dog</option>
      
    </select> 

<select id="dog" name="subselector" class="subselector" style="display:none">
  <option value="">Choose an item</option>
  <option value="bulldog">Bulldog</option>
 
</select>






<div style='display:none;' id="bulldogimges" class="smallimages">
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/pT78gE6pc.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/LiKkRqkeT.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div>
<div class="imgcontainerss" data-image="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/free-bulldog-clipart-031350.gif">
    <img src="https://torcdesign.com/clipart/free-bulldog-clipart-031350.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="55" height="55">
  </div></div>
<h3>result:</h3>
<div> <div id="previewImage">
    </div><a id="download" download="my_image.png" href="#">Download image</a></div>
```

Comment: so how can it be fixed

Comment: no thank you im a big boy i can figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not done anything on your download click.

Just try this.

```
$('#download').click(function(){
   html2canvas($('#firstshirt'),{
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
         var a = document.createElement('a');
         a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg").replace("image/jpeg", "image/octet-stream");
         a.download = 'test.jpg';
         a.click();
       }
    });
});
```